# Basic proof that every polynomial over $\mathbb R$ factorizes into at most quadratic ones

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, real-numbers

Is there a proof without using that in $\mathbb C$ every polynomial factorizes into linear ones that every polynomial over $\mathbb R$ factorizes into linear or quadratic ones?

Comment: Given the quadratic formula, this would immediately imply the result for $\mathbb{C}$, would it not?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft A common way to prove that real polynomials factor into linear and quadratic terms goes via the algebraic closure of $\Bbb C$ and that non-real roots come in complex conjugate pairs. I think the OP want a proof not using $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @Arthur Right, but once you have that proof, the step to $\mathbb{C}$ being algebraically closed is so minor that you would basically have it already.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Not quite. You're very close to proving that the $\Bbb C$ contains the roots of any real polynomial, but you still have a little way to go to prove that $\Bbb C$ is algebraically closed.